# How to upload a file from Google Cloud Storage bucket to Google Earth Engine asset using Python?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I would like to upload a shapefile from a gcs bucket to GEE assets using the Python API.

My understanding of the documentation and the source code of the `UploadTableCommand` is that I should do:

```py
import ee 
from ee.cli.utils import wait_for_task
from pathlib import Path

crs = "EPSG:4326"
assetId = Path("projet/toto/test")
gcs_shp = (tmp_bucket / temp_file.stem).with_suffix(".shp")
request_id = ee.data.newTaskId()[0]
params = {"name": assetId.as_posix(), "souces": [{"uri": str(gcs_shp), "crs": crs}]}
task_id = ee.data.startTableIngestion(request_id, params)["id"]
wait_for_task(task_id, timeout=600)
```

But I get the following error:

> EEException: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "souces" at 'table_manifest': Cannot find field.

Any idea why the API requests a field that is not in the description of the function itself and how I can export my shapefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel bad....

There was a typo in my keys. The correct way is to actually respect the name of the parameter and use "sources" instead of "souces" and "uris" instead of "uri":

```py
params = {"name": assetId.as_posix(), "sources": [{"uris": str(gcs_shp), "crs": crs}]}
```

I'll let the question as an example of how to proceed for further readers as it's not documented by GEE.

Comment: Accept your answer, so it doesn't look unanswered.

Comment: I need to wait 24h before I can do so but I will !